# Can the directional light source simulator representation be rotated?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the simulator a directional light source appears as a green square with a line pointing down. The xyz position of this square changes if you modify the  values, however the rpy values do not seem to be reflected by the square.

Neither does changing the values of the  element change the direction the green square points.

Is this expected behavior (gz 2.2)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7788/can-the-directional-light-source-simulator-representation-be-rotated?/) by [iandanforth](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1053/iandanforth/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Currently, the green box for directional light always points down. Changing the  element will change the direction of the light, but not the green visual. Could you submit an issue for this problem to: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/new

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1